# Find $x^4+y^4$ and $x^3+y^3$ if $x+y=2$ and $x^2+y^2=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $x^4+y^4$ if $x+y=2$ and $x^2+y^2=8$

So i started the problem by nothing that $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2 - 2xy$ but that doesn't help!

I also seen that $x+y=2^1$ and $x^2+y^2=2^3$ so maybe $x^3+y^3=2^5$ and $x^4+y^4=2^7$ but i think this is just coincidence

So how can i solve this problem?

PLEASE i need some help and thanks for all!!

Comment: See [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities).

Comment: higher than my current math level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice

$$(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 64 \implies x^4 + y^4 + 2(xy)^2  = 64$$

and

$$ (x + y )^2 = 4 \implies x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = 4 \implies 2xy = 4 - 8 = -4 \implies xy = -2
$$

$$ \therefore x^4 + y^4 = 64 - 2(xy)^2 = 64 - 2(-2)^2 = 56  $$

Answer (score 1):

Solve the given equations simultaneously to obtain $x=1-\sqrt 3, y=1+\sqrt 3$ or vice versa. Then just compute $x^4+y^4$ directly.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
x^4+y^4&=&(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-\frac12(2xy)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-\frac12\left[(x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2)\right]^2\\
&=&8^2-\frac12(2^2-8)^2=56.
\end{eqnarray}